# std::forward_list::push_front while iterating

Tags: c++, c++11

```
std::forward_list<int> foo {1,2,3,4,5};

for(int i:foo)
{
    if(i==1) foo.push_front(0);

    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

I've tested it on Visual Studio and [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f78f1c9ff546ca69), and from my understanding of how a single linked list is designed there shouldn't be a problem. However, I have little understanding of the internals of forward_list, or stl containers and iterators in general, so I wanted to ask to make sure:

Is above code safe? Or am I invoking UB and it just happens to not start the apocalypse in my small test.

Comment: Insertion into a forward_list does not invalidate iterators.

Comment: I would VTC this as a dupe of my iterator invalidation FAQ, but it's missing an entry for `std::forward_list`.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit can you link me to that FAQ entry please. I can't seem to find it in your profile.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6438086/560648

Comment: Oh, lol, my mistake; it _is_ there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list)

> Adding, removing and moving the elements within the list, or across
>   several lists, does not invalidate the iterators currently referring
>   to other elements in the list. However, an iterator or reference
>   referring to an element is invalidated when the corresponding element
>   is removed (via erase_after) from the list.